# How to Mock rest service

Tags: spring-boot, mockito

I'm wondering how do I mock the rest controller for the code below,

```
public void sendData(ID id, String xmlString, Records record) throws  ValidationException{
        ClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new
                HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(HttpClients.createDefault());
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);

        List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new ArrayList<>();
        messageConverters.add(new StringHttpMessageConverter(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));

        restTemplate.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);

        MultiValueMap<String,String> header = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        header.add("x-api-key",api_key);
        header.add("Content-Type",content_type);
        header.add("Cache-Control",cache_control);
        HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<>(xmlString, header);

        try {
            restTemplate.postForEntity(getUri(id,record), request, String.class);
        }catch (RestClientResponseException e){
            throw new ValidationException("Error occurred while sending a file to some server "+e.getResponseBodyAsString());
        }

    }
```

Any suggestion would be helpful.
I tried to do something like this,

```
  @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
    public class Safe2RestControllerTest {
        private MockRestServiceServer server;
        private RestTemplate restTemplate;
        private restControllerClass serviceToTest;

     @Before
     public void init(){
    //some code for initialization of the parameters used in controller class
        this.server = MockRestServiceServer.bindTo(this.restTemplate).ignoreExpectOrder(true).build();
     }

      @Test
        public void testSendDataToSafe2() throws ValidationException, URISyntaxException {

        //some code here when().then()
        String responseBody = "{\n" +
                    "    \"responseMessage\": \"Validation succeeded, message 
                         accepted.\",\n" +
                    "    \"responseCode\": \"SUCCESS\",\n" +
                    "    2\"responseID\": \"627ccf4dcc1a413588e5e2bae7f47e9c::0d86869e-663a-41f0-9f4c-4c7e0b278905\"\n" +
                    "}";
        this.server.expect(MockRestRequestMatchers.requestTo(uri))
      .andRespond(MockRestResponseCreators.withSuccess(responseBody, 
       MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

        serviceToTest.sendDataToSafe2(id, xmlString, record);
        this.server.verify();
        }
    }
```

This is the test case what I'm trying to do but it still calling actual rest api

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#spring-mvc-test-client

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @JBNizet, you should take a look at `MockRestServiceServer`. It allows you to test Spring components which are using `RestTemplate` to make HTTP calls.

See [MockRestServiceServer](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#spring-mvc-test-client) and [@RestClientTest](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-autoconfigured-rest-client).

Comment: I tried using what @JB Nizet suggested but still it is trying to attempt actual service call and not mocking it. Below is the code snippet I tried with,                         this.server.expect(MockRestRequestMatchers.requestTo(uri))
                .andRespond(MockRestResponseCreators.withSuccess(responseBody, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

Comment: Code is something like this,

Comment: Please ask a new question - comments isn't really the right place